# Nginx reverse proxy: no certificate on proxy, use the backend one

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a small machine that serves as an entry point to my network, let's call it A. I also have two servers on my private network which are not accessible from outside, let's call them B1 and B2.

We will assume that B1 has the private address 1.1.1.1 and B2 the private address 2.2.2.2.

I would like for A to have a basic nginx configuration that proxies any request to `b1.com` and `*.b1.com` to B1, and requests to `b2.com` and `*.b2.com` to B2. B1 and B2 are responsible for handling the required certificates and the endpoints they wish to expose. A would have no ssl certificates stored, and would pass B1 or B2's certificate when they are queried.

Is there a way to achieve this with nginx?

## Current config

I used the following configurations in A, where A has certificates for all necessary domain names. Those are included in the `http` block.

- B1.conf

  ```
  server {
    server_name b1.com;
    server_name *.b1.com;

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location / {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
  }

  server {
    server_name b1.com;
    server_name *.b1.com;

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/b1/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/b1/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
      proxy_pass https://1.1.1.1;

      proxy_pass_request_headers on;
      proxy_pass_header Content-Type;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;

      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;

      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    }
  }
  ```
- B2.conf: identical to above, with `b1` replaced with `b2`, and `1.1.1.1` replaced with `2.2.2.2`.

## Desired behaviour

I would like to be able to remove the ssl section of the configuration, so that when I connect to b1.com, A returns the ssl certificate served by B1 directly.
In a sense, I'd like A to be completely transparent, as it would only pass the requests and replies around.

This way, I can have A configured once and for all, and any change I wish to make would only have to be made on B1 or B2.
For example, if I want a new domain name `new.b1.com`, I would only need to update the certificate on B1, whereas now I also need to update the certificate on A.

## Possible solution

I know that one solution would be to make the proxy connections to B1 and B2 through HTTP, but I would like to know if it is possible to do something else for the following reasons:

- B1 and B2 are owned by different people, who are OK with sharing, but would like to keep their configuration as close to home as possible, i.e. avoid making changes on A if possible,
- having HTTPS connections between A and B1/B2 would allow the traffic in the private network to stay encrypted.

I was also wondering if streams could do something like this?